# Netlogo: find next target discounting previous targets

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to get my agents to calculate the next patch target once they have reached their first target. A target is defined as the (highest patch influence value / distance to agent). The next target needs to be calculated using this same procedure, but also discounting any previous targets from the equation.

I have attempted to create a patch-set to include all targets, although I'm not sure if it works.

My issue is how to create a to-report function that calculates the next highest-influence-value. I've gotten completely stuck with this final part of my procedure.

My initial reporter function is:

```
to-report highest-influence
  let available-target patches with [influence > 0] ;and not any? patches with [pcolor = green]
  report max-one-of available-target [influence / distance myself]
end
```

But I'm not sure how to have the next reporter function use the same parameters while also discounting any previous targets

```
to-report next-highest-influence
  ; patches with [influence > 0] and not part of patch set
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've provided the full code.

```
breed [walkers walker]

walkers-own [traveled?  ;; parameter to keep track of if a walker has traveled to a target yet or not 
             target ]

patches-own [influence influence-set] ;highest-influence

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  define-patches
  create-walkers num-walkers
  ask walkers [
    setxy 0 0
    set heading 90
    let streets neighbors with [pcolor = black]
    ifelse any? streets in-cone 1 25
        [fd 1]
        [move-to one-of streets in-radius 1]
    set traveled? false    ;; so that walkers know they have not yet moved to a target
    ]
  ask walkers [
    define-target ]
end

to define-patches
  ask n-of 100 patches [
    set pcolor white
    ]
  ask n-of 40 patches with [pcolor = white] [set influence random 5 set pcolor blue set plabel influence]
  ask patches [set influence-set patches with [pcolor = green] ]
end

to define-target        ;; this defines the initial destination of walkers 
  if traveled? = false [
  set target highest-influence
  ask target [set pcolor green]
    face target ]
end

to new-target            ;; this defines subsequent desinations after walkers have reached inital target 
  if traveled? = true [
    set target next-highest-influence
    ask target [set pcolor green + 2]
       face target ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;run-time procedure;;;;;;;;;;

to go
   ask walkers [
    if distance target > 1
      [ travel-walkers
        leave-a-trail 
        set traveled? true ]
    if distance target = 1
      [ stop
        new-target
        travel-walkers
        leave-a-trail
       ]
    ]
  tick
end

to travel-walkers  
    ask walkers [
       move-towards-target 
   ]  
end

to move-towards-target
 ask walkers [ 
  ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 != white or any? other turtles-here
    [ Move-Function ]
    [ Avoid-Function ]
  ]  
end

to Move-Function
  let t target
  face min-one-of all-possible-moves [distance t]
  fd 1
end

to Avoid-Function
  let t target
  face min-one-of all-possible-moves [distance t]
end

to leave-a-trail
  ask patch-here [set pcolor grey]
end

;;;;;; reporter calculations ;;;;;;
to-report highest-influence
  let available-target patches with [influence > 0] ;and not any? patches with [pcolor = green]
  report max-one-of available-target [influence / distance myself]
end

to-report next-highest-influence
  ; patches with [influence > 0] and not part of patch set
end

to-report all-possible-moves
  report patches in-radius 1 with [pcolor != white and distance myself  <= 1 and distance myself  > 0 and plabel = "" ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `member?` primitive to do that. Check out the simplified toy model below (I didn't use your code as I'm not sure how you'd want to implement and there are some interface pieces i would need to set up to run it. Check out the [MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

```
turtles-own [ visited-list ]
patches-own [ influence ]

to setup-member?
  ca
  crt 1 [ set visited-list [] ]
  ask patches [ set influence 0 ]
  ask n-of 5 patches [ set influence 5 + random 50 ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go-member?
  ask turtles [
    let target highest-influence
    ifelse target != nobody [
      face target
      ifelse distance target > 1 [
        fd 1
      ] [
        move-to target
        ask target [ set pcolor red]
        set visited-list lput target visited-list
      ]
    ] [ print "No targets remaining." ]
  ]
  tick
end

to-report highest-influence
  let to-visit patches with [ 
    influence > 0 and 
    not member? self [visited-list] of myself ]
  report max-one-of to-visit [ influence / ( distance myself )]
end
```

The reported returns the patch with the highest influence/distance value that is **not** a member of the turtle's `visited-list`. Initially, no patches are a member of the list, but as the turtle visits each target, it adds the target to the `visited-list` so that patch is no longer considered.